# How to delete the first element of a row so that the whole row deleted from a list?

Tags: python-2.7

My list looks as follow:

```
items = []

a = "apple", 1.23

items.append(a)

b = "google", 2.33

items.append(b)

c = "ibm", 4.35

items.append(c)
```

Now  I will just remove the row of "apple" by just giving the name of "apple".

How to do?

Comment: Step 1: find the index of the item you want to delete. Step 2: delete the item at that index. What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use a proper data structure. In your case, a dict will do the trick.

```
items = {"apple": 1.23, "google": 2.33, "ibm": 4.35}
```

To delete, use:

```
items.pop("apple", None)
```

Comment: Using pop() seems better.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert `items` into a dictionary, delete the entry with key `apple` and return the dictionary items:

```
>>> items
[('apple', 1.23), ('google', 2.33), ('ibm', 4.35)]
>>> d = dict(items)
>>> del d['apple']
>>> items = d.items()
>>> items
[('ibm', 4.35), ('google', 2.33)]
```

In python 3, you should cast `d.items` with `list` as `.items()` returns a `dict_items` object which is *iterable* but not *subscriptable*:

```
>>> items = list(d.items())
```

Comment: Hi, as I tried the del d['apple'], I got error: KeyError: 'apple'

Comment: Maybe the del d[] is from python3? I use python2.

Comment: Means the apple entry has already been deleted. To avoid errors you can use: `d.pop('apple', None)` which returns `None` when the key is not found

Answer (score 0):

Since I canonly accept one answer and truely to say I am not 100% satisfied with both, so I haven't accpted any one. Hope it's OK for you all.

I do followings, a combination of both of yours:

```
d = dict(items)
d.pop("apple", None)
myitem = d.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is that of using a dictionary, as suggested by @Sricharan Madasi and @Moses Koledoye. However, provided that the OP seems to prefer to arrange data as a **list of tuples**, he may find this function useful:

```
def my_func(lst, key):
    return [(name, number) for (name, number) in lst if name != key]
```

The following interactive session demonstrates its usage:

```
>>> items = [('apple', 1.23), ('google', 2.33), ('ibm', 4.35)]
>>> my_func(items, 'apple')
[('google', 2.33), ('ibm', 4.35)]
>>> my_func(items, 'ibm')
[('apple', 1.23), ('google', 2.33)]
>>> my_func(items, 'foo')
[('apple', 1.23), ('google', 2.33), ('ibm', 4.35)]
```